# Problem with Food and Drink store not showing up in my build menu

Tags: fallout-4

I'm having a weird random problem where just the Food and Drink store is not showing up in the build menu-Sommerville in particular. I have the bar set up at various other settlements, so I don't get why its not available here.

I've tried leaving and coming back, reloading a save, but it still isn't available. Does anyone know if there's a fix for this or has experienced this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What platform are you on? Do you have any mods installed? When you say it's not showing up, is it greyed out or disabled, or really just not even there at all?

Comment: Are all three levels of the bar not showing up?

Comment: @DCShannon well odd thing...it just reappeared. I guess it's just buggy (Xbox one)